# jquery two select connects

Tags: jquery

I am trying to connect two HTML `select` elements. What I want is that when item is `select1` select disable or remove in `select2`. I tried so

```
var selector = "#select2 option [value = '" + id_familia + "']";
$(selector).remove();
```

but as may be updated `#select2`? ie selected item `#item1` and item `#select2` remove but when i select again any item `#select1` item1 no show in `#select2`.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I think you got it almost correct. Just try to remove that space between `option` and `[`. Try: `var selector = "#select2 option[value='" + id_familia + "']";` . Also make sure `id_familia` has the correct value from `#select1`

Comment: Translation: "When an item in select #select1 is selected, disable or remove the same element in #select2"? They should give reputation for figuring out what the asker is actually asking sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it almost correct. Just try to remove that space between `option` and `[`.

Try:

```
var selector = "#select2 option[value='" + id_familia + "']";
```

Also make sure `id_familia` has the correct value from `#select1`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove it, what if user changes selection again? My coin:

```
var $select1 = $('#select1');
var $select2 = $('#select2');

$select1.on('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = $select1.val();
    $select2.find('option').prop('disabled', false).filter('[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

So on every change in select1, all options in select2 are enabled except option selected in select1.